Help figuring out how to/ the best way to get power to a new house
We are hoping to build a house that will be located about 600 feet from the nearest transformer. We have two options. 1) Let the power company cut down a lot of trees, put in more poles, run about 450 feet of above ground wire, and get a new transformer closer to the house (which we can then couple with a 150 feet of underground secondary power). 2) Run off the existing transformer with 600 feet of two parallel strands of 250MCM wire.
We really really really don't want to cut down the extra trees. But we also want the power to be stable.
We have not been able to get good professional advice on this. Reading on Southwire suggests that even drawing just 200 amps through the 600 foot run gives us a 6.6% voltage drop. Which is more than is recommended. If this is still stable, then we save the trees.
Any thoughts or recommendations?

Any chance of putting the wires underground?  Above ground wires and trees are an extra problem spot.

Wire does not stop at 250 MCM. A single strand of 500 MCM does the same job and usually costs less than 2 parallel strands and the special equipment at each end for paralleling conductors. 750 and 1000 MCM are available. There's also (depending on power company cooperativeness) running the high voltage line underground  (smaller wire, thicker insulation, usually needs concrete cover for protection,  but might cost less) and putting the transformer 50 feet or less from the house. And the 3rd option of taking the house off-grid and making your own power.

The power company refuses to consider running the primary line underground. We've tried to push them, they won't budge.  We would LOVE to go off-grid, but the lot is not well situated for wind or solar. It's heavily wooded, very north, and not on a ridge or something. I will make inquiries about the bigger wire. We were not given that option by the person who would be doing the install. Thanks!

Any chance of running the driveway where the power line goes?  Just you might need to cut trees for the drive anyway, it might reduce the amount of trees cut.

That's what we are hoping to do, but we are told that the driveway will then likely need to be 50 feet wide, rather than 20.  Which is sad.

If the power company will terminate your service (place the meter) somewhere near their existing transformer an let you take things from there, you could put your own step-up transformer at that location and run higher voltage (say 480) from that point to a step-down transformer at the house. You could save money on wire and conduit and spend it on transformers. Also if the meter is there, whether you use your own transformers or not, you could route and size your line underground as you wish, near or under the driveway, as per NEC and local jurisdiction rules.
